# What book introduces sound for laypeople trying to learn phonetics, but who loathe physics?

Tags: reference-request

I'm reading about sound only because I like linguistics. I loathe, and have never taken any, physics. But I can do high school math, as I like statistics (not mathematical physics).

I'm too dumb to understand even the explanations of harmonics/overtones, resonance, formants in [*Vowels and Consonants* (3rd Edition 2012)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1444334298) and [*Phonetics for Dummies* (2013)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1118505085).  Thus please recommend something readable that's more rudimentary?  Thanks!

No library near me owns [*Sound: A Very Short Introduction*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Sound-Very-Short-Introduction-Introductions/dp/0198708440). [*The Science of Sound*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0805385657) feels too advanced.

Comment: J.C. Catford's _A Practical Introduction to Phonetics_. It's set up for autodidacts to teach themselves by experiment exactly how to make various kinds of sounds. There's nothing like it.

Comment: @jlawler Thanks!!! Not enough rep. to upvote your comment though.

Comment: It sounds like you're not interested in phonetics, you're interested in something (smaller) that some phoneticians do. You can't learn intro phonetics without getting a grasp on basic physics, but you can learn what the letters are about with the Pullum/Ladusaw book, or something about making sounds with Catford. Phonetics is not about "making sounds". I think you'd be better served by *not* assuming you care about phonetics, and introspect about what it is that does interest you. Why do you care about the sounds ʕ, ɯ (if you do)? The answer can point you in the right direction.